# Do we need to define the shell on file that include only functions?

Tags: bash, shell-script, function

I am wondering if we need to add shell title:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

on a script, `second.sh`, which only defines a function, and is called from another script, `script.sh`.

For example, with `script.sh` containing

```
#!/bin/bash

source second.sh

func1 "make amerika great again "

echo $I_AM_SAY
```

and `second.sh` containing only a function that is called from the first script:

```
X=soon

function func1 {
   fun=$1
I_AM_SAY=$fun$X
}
```

Do we need to define `second.sh` instead as:

```
#!/bin/bash
X=soon

function func1 {
   fun=$1
I_AM_SAY=$fun$X
}
```

or as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

X=soon

function func1 {
   fun=$1
I_AM_SAY=$fun$X
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don’t need a shebang line: the running shell sources the script directly, it doesn’t start a new shell (which is the whole point of sourcing a script), so neither it nor the kernel need to know which shell to use to run it.

If you want to prevent the `second.sh` script from being invoked at all, you can add a

```
#!/usr/bin/false
```

shebang line.

Comment: thank you , why you put the strange hat on your head?

Comment: https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you only `source` the file from another script, the hashbang doesn't get interpreted (it's just a comment there). It might work as a comment for the reader to remind them that the script uses functionality specific to a particular shell, though. Of course, you should mention that in plain text in comments too, since, you do have a description of your script in a comment near the top of the file anyway, right?